# Nominal Interest

Tags: finance, actuarial-science

The question :
At a nominal rate of interest $i$, convertible semiannually, the present value
of a series of payments of $1$ at the end of every $2$ years, forever, is $5.89$. Calculate $i$.

I attempted this by solving for the PV of a perpetuity $5.89 = \frac{1}{i}$ which is $i=0.16977$

Then I plug it into the formula $1+i=(1+\frac{i^{(2)}}{2})^2$ and $i^{(2)}= 0.163188$

I know the final answer is $i=8\%$, so where did I make a mistake?

EDIT:
The problem was that I was raising my expression to the second power instead of the fourth. I overlooked that it was being compounded every $2$ years. So semi-annual for two years equals $4$ periods, therefore I need to raise it to the fourth power. $1+i=(1+\frac{i^{(2)}}{2})^4$ and $i^{(2)}= 0.07996$

Comment: Your formula would make sense if the annuity was received annually.  As it is received every two years what you want is $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \left( \frac 1{1+i} \right)^{2k}=5.89$.  I get $i≈0.081563$

Comment: What does $k$ mean and go up to?

Comment: $k$ is the summation index, and the range is indicated ($k$ runs from $1$ to $\infty$).  $2k$ represents the years...thus $2k$ goes $2,4,6,\cdots$.

Comment: How did you calculate $i$ then?

Comment: It's just a geometric series!  $|r|<1\implies \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} r^{2k}=r^2\times \frac 1{1-r^2}$.

Comment: Ok thank you, but why is it $\frac{1}{1+i}$ in the first place? Isn't the PV of a perpetuity $\frac{1}{i}$?

Comment: Once again, you are relying on a formula that works in one case (annual annuity).  In that case you get $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left( \frac 1{1+i} \right)^k=\frac 1{1+i}\times \frac 1{1-\frac 1{1+i}}=\frac 1i$.  In your case, the algebra is (slightly) more complex.

Comment: As a general bit of advice:  don't rely on specific formulas.  Usually these rely on a very precise set of facts.  Instead, focus on the algebra that generates those formulas.  Usually, that algebra can be adapted to fit whatever facts are present.

Comment: @lulu the $i$ in your formula is the effetcive annual interest rate! you have to evaluate the nominal interest rate convertible semiannually, and then $i^{(2)}=2(\sqrt{1.081563}-1)\approx 0.07996$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The effective bi-annual interest rate is $j$ such that
$$
\left(1+\frac{i^{(2)}}{2}\right)^4=1+j
$$
So you have
$$
5.89=a_{\overline{\infty}|j}=\frac{1}{j}\quad\Longrightarrow\quad j=\frac{1}{5.89}
$$
and 
$$
i^{(2)}=2\left[\left(1+j\right)^{1/4}-1\right]\approx 7.99648\%
$$
so we can say that the interest converttible semiannually is $i=i^{(2)}\approx 8\%$.

Answer (score 1):

The payment is every two years so you should have $i= \sqrt{1+0.169779287
}-1\approx 0.08156335$

Your second expression may be backwards, and you could try $2(\sqrt{1+0.08156335}-1)\approx 0.07996$ which is close to $8\%$

Comment: What formulas did you use for your answer?

Comment: In effect I inverted the two-year compounding function $(1+i)^2-1$ to $\sqrt{1+i}-1$ and applied that twice to get from every two years to every half year, and then double the final result

Comment: The first formula is the effetcive annual interest rate and the second is the nominal interest rate convertible semiannually.